# How to display {% django block %} dynamically with for loop?

Tags: django, django-templates

**Hello Awesome People!**

I'm building a dashboard for my website, in the left section, I have a menu containing multiple items : `Home`, `Messenger`, `Job Offers` ....
When creating an account, Users are able to choose their items, re-order or remove.

I have `Menu` & `Item` models,

```
class Menu(models.Model):
     items = models.ManyToManyField('Item',blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     unique_key = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
     url = ......
```

For the menu of the user, in my `base_template` I display the items of the current users with for loop. With a CSS class I want to highlight the current view, the current item.
When the user visits his messenger, I want to highlight that item messenger with a CSS class.

```
 <ul>
     {% for item in user.menu.items.all %}
     <li class='{% block item.unique_key %}{% endblock %}'>
          <a href="{{item.url}}"> {{item.name}}</a>
     </li>
     {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Now, when being in `messenger.html` for example, knowing that I have a `unique_key` for messenger called `item_messenger`, I do

```
{% block 'item_messenger' %}active{% endfor%}
```

It's not working, the item `Messenger` or whatever I choose doesn't become highlighted, I wonder why? 
**Is there another way to achieve that?**

Any hint will be helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't understand why you want to do that with a block. Why not just a variable which you compare with the unique key? `<li class="{% if active_key == item.unique_key %}active{% endblock %}">`

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did it because before having to display the elements in this way with a loop, I had them in the template as a normal list individually containing a class `<li class = '{% block item_name %} {% endblock %}'>`. And then at the top of every page, I add `{% block item_name %} active {% endblock %}`. I already have all my pages with the `block` tag at the top, which is why I had to do with `block` in a loop. The way you show me, I had already thought, but it will require me to have `active_key` as a context variable in each view; I have a lot of views.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to have the block tag interpret a variable as it's name. That doesn't work.

You will need to pass along the active item's key in the template context and then in your `base_template` you can just do a simple if statement to add the `active` class to the correct entry.

```
<ul>
    {% for item in user.menu.items.all %}
        <li class='{% if item.unique_key == active_key %}active{% endif %}'>
            <a href="{{item.url}}"> {{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you take a look at my reply above (Question comments), so you will understand why I did it with block